# RegistryState not working on console application

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I have created a Windows Form application for smart device in c# which will raise an 
event whenever there is a change in registry data. I have used RegistryState and the following code from msdn site. I am able to successfully raise the event.

```
RegistryState state; 
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SystemState state;  // This instance will go out of scope if defined here

    RegistryState state = new RegistryState("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\MyKey", "MyValue");
    state.Changed += new ChangeEventHandler(state_Changed);
}
```

But when I use the same code and create a console application, event is not getting triggered.

What could be the reason? Does RegistryState  have any limitations?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use Reflector to dig into it, but my strong suspicion is that down in its depths the `ReegistryState` class works a lot like the `SHChangeNotifyRegister` API.  It uses Windows Messaging to signal state changes, so it must have a message pump that's watching for and dispatching those messages and some place to send them when they come in.  A console app doesn't have a message pump, and therefore while the message is likely getting queued that the registry has changed, there's nothing pulling that message off and forwarding it to your `RegistryState` handler.

It would be easy enough to test (and work around).  Just add a message pump to your app that does a the usual GetMessage/TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage periodically.

Comment: I think the WindowsCE.Forms.MessageWindow class will do 90% of the work for you. MSDN has an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.messagewindow(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It won't create the message pump.  Application.Run does that, and the CF doesn't have one that takes no Form, so you have to work around that.

Comment: Nuts. You're right. Well, that's much less useful than I thought it was.